# Build the string dynamically based on the length in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

My aim is to generate a `string`. which has following conditions.

First i will take an empty string and start building the string based on length.

Example:

I have an `empty string` `""`.

In the first step i want to add a `string` till 8 characters, means first my `string` is `""` then till 8 characters my string should contain the value `Hiwor` so finally my string will be `Hiwor` if there is no value empty value should be padded in the `string`.

In the second step i want to add the string `meena` till 10 positions , so my final string should be `Hiwor   meena`. In this way i want to build my string. Ho can i achieve this. Can you please help me.

Sample:
initial string `""`

first step adding string `Hiwor` till `8 positions`,

so final string should be `Hiwor`

second step adding string `meena` till `10 postions`

so final string should be `Hiwor   meena`  .

Till now i tried like this

```
 Dictionary<string, Int16> transLine = new Dictionary<string, Int16>();

            transLine.Add("ProductCode", 1);

            transLine.Add("ApplicantFirstName", 12);

            transLine.Add("ApplicantMiddleInitial", 1);

            transLine.Add("partner", 1);

            transLine.Add("employee", 8);

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("grouplife");
            list.Add("meena");
            list.Add("d");
            list.Add("yes");
            list.Add("yes");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var listItem in list)
            {
                foreach (var item in transLine)
                {
                    if (listItem == item.Key)
                    {
                        var length = item.Value;
                        sb.Insert(length, item.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
```

but it is throwing me an exception.`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: "Hiwor" has 5, "Hiwor   meena" 12 characters. So where do the 8 and the 10 in your example come from?

Comment: Can you also mention what you have done so far to achieve it? and where are you stuck?

Comment: So? There is no question in your "question". What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Thomas if there is no string it has to be padded with empty space

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Uncompleted questions get uncompleted answers. Check string Builder:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly define an extension method for StringBuilder:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AppendPadded(this StringBuilder builder, string value, int length);
    {
        builder.Append($"{value}{new string(' ', length)}".Substring(0, length));
    }
    public static void AppendPadded(this StringBuilder builder, int value, int length);
    {
        builder.Append($"{new string('0', length)}{value}".Reverse().ToString().Substring(0, length).Reverse().ToString());
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendPadded("Hiwor", 8);
builder.AppendPadded("meena", 10);
return builder.ToString();
```

Or with your example:

```
foreach (string item in list)
    builder.AppendPadded(item, transLine[item]);
```

EDIT: Ok, so looks like you want to be able to define a format then build the string using it. Try:

(you will need to reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.Reflection for this)

```
public abstract class AnItem
{
    private static int GetLength(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        StringLengthAttribute attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;
        if (attribute == null)
            throw new Exception($"StringLength not specified for {property.Name}");
        return attribute.MaxLength();
    }
    private string GetPropertyValue(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            return property.GetValue(this);
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            return property.GetValue(this).ToString();
        else
            throw new Exception($"Property '{property.Name}' is not a supported type");
    }
    private static void SetPropertyValue(object item, PropertyInfo property, string value)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            property.SetValue(item, value, null);
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            property.SetValue(item, int.Parse(value), null);
        else
            throw new Exception($"Property '{property.Name}' is not a supported type");
    }
    public string GetPaddedString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            builder.AppendPadded(GetPropertyValue(property), GetLength(property));
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    public static T CreateFromPaddedString<T>(string paddedString) where T : AnItem, new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        int offset = 0;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            int length = GetLength(property);
            if (offset + length > paddedString.Length)
                throw new Exception("The string is too short");
            SetPropertyValue(item, property, paddedString.Substring(offset, length)));
            offset += length;
        }
        if (offset < paddedString.Length)
            throw new Exception("The string is too long");
        return item;
    }
}
public class MyItem : AnItem
{
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(12)]
    public string ApplicantFirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string ApplicantMiddleInitial { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Partner { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it:

```
MyItem item = new MyItem
{
    ProductCode = "grouplife",
    ApplicantFirstName = "meena",
    ApplicantMiddleInitial = "d",
    Partner = "yes",
    Employee = "yes"
};

string paddedString = item.GetPaddedString();
```

And to read a string to get an item:

```
MyItem item = AnItem.CreateFromPaddedString<MyItem>(paddedString);
```

Comment: updated. note: your lengths will cause data to be trimmed

Comment: You can either use .ToString when setting the values, or you can remove the string exception in GetPaddedString and use property.GetValue(this).ToString() in the AppendPadded call. Not sure if the compiler will complain having a StringLength attribute against an int or not.

Comment: i want a solution for 1 more problem , i want the solution for vice versa, means i want to  split the above generated string in to pieces based on the length we mentioned above each and every property. can you please help me out with this.

Comment: Added CreateFromPaddedString method. Also neatened up by moving property getting and setting to separate methods and added in handling for integers. You can extend the GetPropertyValue and SetPropertyValue methods easily if you need to handle more types.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am facing one more problem with the above, the issue i have a value as 0 and string length as 7 when i use the above code to build my string it is building like "0      ", means only 1 position is filled with 0 remaining length is being filled with empty

Comment: no my requirement is to build the string with ""0000000" instead of "0     
 " please help me out with this

Comment: Added another method for ints in the StringBuilderExtensions

Comment: WARNING: This answer has a bug in the extension class. It doesn't even compile because there is no constructor for the string class that accepts as first parameter a string but only a char. This creates confusion as you can see from this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116871/string-builder-with-generate-space-for-string-and-0s-for-number#69116963

Comment: Yes, the characters were enclosed with double quotes instead of single quotes. Edited to resolve!

Answer (score 1):

At first I want to say something more about your exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

As the exception already said. The problem is that you want to access a position within your new `StringBuilder sb` which does not exists.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

After this line your new `sb` is empty. There is no single character in it. So you can only access the index at position `0`. But almost in your first iteration of the inner for-each loop you want to target the index `1` and try to insert your string at the position `1`, which does not exists.

```
// length: 1 and item.Key: ProductCode
sb.Insert(length, item.Key);
```

---

So how to solve this. You can use a feature from String.Format() or since C#6 the string interpolation.

So for example:

**`String.Format()`**

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);      // sb: []
sb.Append(string.Format("{0, -8}", "Hiwor"));  // sb: [Hiwor   ]
sb.Append(string.Format("{0,-10}", "meena"));  // sb: [Hiwor   meena     ]
```

**C#6 String Interpolation**

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);  // sb: []
sb.Append($"{"Hiwor", -8}");               // sb: [Hiwor   ]
sb.Append($"{"meena", -10}");              // sb: [Hiwor   meena     ]

// ...
```

---

*Targeting your edit:*

*With your given list items you will never get a match with any of your dictionary keys.*

Comment: Didn't know you could pad strings using that format. Nice and simple