# string builder with generate space for string and 0's for number

Tags: c#

According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48805101/7273263 answer i am taking this code

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendPadded(this StringBuilder builder, string value, int length);
        {
            builder.Append($"{value}{new string(" ", length)}".Substring(0, length));
        }
        public static void AppendPadded(this StringBuilder builder, int value, int length);
        {
            builder.Append($"{new string("0", length)}{value}".Reverse().ToString().Substring(0, length).Reverse().ToString());
        }
    }
```

But am gtting comipler warning for Please check

I need to genearate  space based on legth of string and trail zero for number..Please some on help .i need to use this extension

Usage:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendPadded("Hiwor", 8);     //space if less than 8 
builder.AppendPadded("meena", 10);  //space if less than 10
return builder.ToString();
```

ERROR:

> *Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'  Web.API E:\WorkSpace\BankingSolutions\CPS\Web.API\Extensions\StringBuilderExtension.cs  13  Active*

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages, since this makes it harder to read and makes it impossible to search for. Copy the error message instead.

Comment: Sory updated in the question

Comment: I'm surprised now that the linked answer got 4 upvotes, since it doesn't even compile because of many errors there. The question should be a comment to the linked answer

Comment: @Cid Yes _sometimes_, votes cannot be relied on.

Comment: A bad answer is something that should be addressed in a way or another. Posted a comment there to point users here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple bug.  The `string` constructor you are using is looking for a first argument `char` (not `string`) - so say `new string(' ', length)` instead of `new string(" ", length)` etc

Ref: [String(Char,Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) (Thanks to @Fildor below for the nudge)

Comment: For reference: [String(Char, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_)

Comment: And don't worry too much about the downvotes.  It irritates me that people criticise your use of an image that gives all the info they need to answer your question.  It seems there is more reward in finding fault with the way a question is asked than in trying to answer it.  (With that said, it's much more helpful to get full depth of exception info which is not immediately apparent in an image (which also takes up a lot more space).  G'luck.

Comment: ~~The~~ One of the problems with images is: you cannot copy from them. That's why it's generally frowned upon.

Comment: @AlanK people with vision impairement cannot see images, however, they can *read* texts. Search engines cannot searches text within images

Comment: @Cid not arguing, it's just a sad irony that after 10 views nobody answered the (simple) question but there were 2 downvotes.  Why not help the OP and suggest how (and why) the question could be improved at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Just to propose an alternative, have a look at this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendPadded("asdf", 10);
        sb.AppendPadded(1234, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}

public static class StrungBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AppendPadded(this StringBuilder builder, string appendix, int width)
    {
        builder.Append(appendix.PadRight(width, ' '));
    }
    
    public static void AppendPadded(this StringBuilder builder, int appendix, int width)
    {
        builder.Append(appendix.ToString().PadLeft(width, '0'));
    }
}
```

In Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1rNKfg

Output:

```
asdf      0000001234
```

I didn't run any horses, so I cannot say if one or the other is faster or more memory efficient. But *at least* I tend to find this more readable.

Alternatively to the above, you could also use [StringBuilder.AppendFormat(String, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat?view=net-5.0#System_Text_StringBuilder_AppendFormat_System_String_System_Object_)  in conjunction with [String Format: Control Spacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#control-spacing)

Comment: Thank you very much @Fildor..but alleady accepted answer

Comment: No problem at all. This answer more avoid your problem than solves it. Just wanted to give you an alternative to the implementation you got from the awkwardly high voted answer.